# Number of Hamiltonian cycles in $K{n,n}$ which contain specific edges

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Suppose $K_{n,n}$ is a complete bipartite graph with vertices on left and right indexed by {${l_1, l_2, ..., l_n}$} and {$r_1, r_2, ..., r_n$} for $n \geq 3$.

I would like to ask how many Hamiltonian cycles in $K_{n,n}$ contain the edge {$l_1, r_1$}?

On the other hand, what about the Hamiltonian cycles in $K_{n,n}$ which **DO NOT** contain any edge from {$l_1, r_1$}, {$r_1, l_2$}, {$l_2, r_2$}?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back off of @Donald, I’ll answer the second question. Following @Donald’s reasoning there are in total $\frac{n}{2}((n-1)!)^2$ Hamiltonian cycles for $K_{n,n}$ provided $n>1$. We divide by two because $n!(n-1)!$ inadvertently assigns a clockwise/counter-clockwise direction to each Hamiltonian cycle. In order to consider such Hamiltonian cycles that don’t include ${l_1,r_1}$ we must multiply this value by $\frac{{n-1\choose 2}}{{n\choose 2}} $ since $l_1$ has to choose $2$ vertices out of $n$ to connect to, but we are restricted to choosing out of a smaller pool of $n-1$ vertices.

Continuing in this fashion, we see that the number of Hamiltonian cycles that don’t include those three edges  is 
$$\frac{n}{2}((n-1)!)^2\frac{{n-1\choose 2}}{{n\choose 2}}\frac{{n-2\choose 2}}{{n-1\choose 2}}\frac{{n-2\choose 2}}{{n-1\choose 2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}((n-2)!)^2(n-3)^2(n-2)$$

Comment: you mentioned $n>1$ i am wondering is it also true for $n \geq 3$. However, is there a typo ? (replacement of the n of the term n / 2 to $n^{2}$ ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes the statement should be true for $n\geq 3$. I specified $n>1$ to guarantee the expression evaluates to an integer. In the case $n=1$ there are no Hamiltonian cycles. I’m not sure I understand what typo you’re referring to. $n$ is definitely meant to be divided by $2$.

Comment: I just find that $n((n-1)!)^{2} = n!(n-1)!$ , a careless mistake.... btw would you give some hints about the number of H with {$l_1, r_1$} and {$l_2, r_2$} ? Since they are not connect, i can't use @Donald's method

Comment: You’re right. It was confusing for me to bring that up out of nowhere, but those two expressions are equivalent since $n\times (n-1)!$ is the same as just taking $n!$. Someone actually happened to post that question an hour after you made yours. My answer is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455014/number-of-hamiltonian-cycles-in-kn-n/3455194#3455194

Answer (score 1):

A Hamiltonian cycle will have the following form
\begin{eqnarray*}
l_1 r_1 l_{i_1} r_{j_1} \cdots l_{i_{n-1}} r_{j_{n-1}} 
\end{eqnarray*}
There are $n-1 $ choices for $i_1$ an $j_1$.  There are $n-2 $ choices for $i_2$ and $j_2$, and so on until,there are $1 $ choice for $i_{n-1}$ and $j_{n-1}$. So that makes $((n-1)!)^2$ Hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: The second answer is incorrect. This can be seen from the $n=2$ case.

Comment: how about with the edge {$l_1, r_1$} and { $l_2, r_2$} ? thanks so much